# No visible output of calculated values in AngluarJS

Tags: angularjs

I am a bit confused: I currently work on a project with AngularJS (1.8) where I intend to do some calculations. Now the weird thing is this: Inside my controller the values all appear and get used but on my HTML they don't. Fiddled a bit around with my HTML but I still can't wrap my head around the fact that the calculated values don't get display.
As the groundwork I used a [seed from GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) - had to update the dependencies, obviously. I looked high and low for a reason so either I am shit at formulating questions or there is something different going on  and I made avid use of the AngularJS documentation - just to get that out of the way.

```js
'use strict';
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and core components
angular.module('Data', []).controller("Main", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.angle = 17;
  $scope.velocity = 20;
  $scope.height = 0;
  console.log("enter controller");
  //console.log($scope);
  /*$scope.calculate=function(angle,0){
    $scope.time=((angle*Math.PI)/180));
  };
  $scope.calculate=function(0,velocity){
    $scope.distance=velocity*3.6;
  };*/
  $scope.calculate = function(angle, velocity) {
    console.log("enter calc");
    $scope.height = angle * velocity;
    console.log($scope.height, angle, velocity);

    return $scope.height;
  }
  console.log("exit calc");
  //console.log($scope);
}]);
```

```html
<body ng-app="Data" ng-controller="Main">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <label>Winkel:<input type="number" ng-model="angle"></label>
  <label>Geschwindigkeit:<input type="number" ng-model="velocity"></label>

  <!--<label ng-model="time"></label>
    <label ng-model="distance"></label>
    <label ng-model="height"></label>-->

  <input type="button" value="Berechnen" class='btn btn-default' ng-click="calculate(angle,velocity)">
  <p>Bei einem Winkel {{angle}}° und einer Geschwindigkeit von {{velocity}} erreicht die Masse bei einer Wurfzeit von <span ng-model="time"></span> eine Wurfhöhe <span ng-model="height"></span> und eine Wurfweite <span ng-model="distance"></span></p>
  <!--<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#!/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>-->

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div>AngularJS seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: "They do not seem to work" is not clear behaviour. I turned your code into a runnable snippet, and the code seems to work, is that correct?

Comment: Well, yes it does run but the value $scope.height does not get displayed. Which is my problem. And I don't know why - everything seems to be in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` is to change the value, `ng-bind` is to put the value of a variable into the HTML:

```js
'use strict';
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and core components
angular.module('Data', []).controller("Main", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.angle = 17;
  $scope.velocity = 20;
  $scope.height = 0;

  $scope.calculate = function(angle, velocity) {
    $scope.height = angle * velocity;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<body ng-app="Data" ng-controller="Main">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <label>Winkel:<input type="number" ng-model="angle"></label>
  <label>Geschwindigkeit:<input type="number" ng-model="velocity"></label>

  <input type="button" value="Berechnen" class='btn btn-default' ng-click="calculate(angle,velocity)">
  <p>Bei einem Winkel {{angle}}° und einer Geschwindigkeit von {{velocity}} erreicht die Masse bei einer Wurfzeit von <span ng-bind="time"></span> eine Wurfhöhe <span ng-bind="height"></span> und eine Wurfweite <span ng-bind="distance"></span></p>

  <div>AngularJS seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I had tried it with ng-bind before but I must've done something wrong or it didn't work. Now it does - see Clarkes Laws.